# Disable asset bundling in Webpack 5

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

When I reference an asset in Webpack 5 it creates a copy of it by default. For example a font file in `./assets/fonts/myfont.woff2` gets copied to `./b27297c148a7ef314ce2.woff2` which is very useful when working with a source and a dist folder. Howerver, I need to use the same asset directory from my source files and the bundled css file. Is there a way to disable the file copying and only update the path to the ressource files according to the destination of the bundled output file?

**Update:**

I've managed to set the copy destination equal to the source destination of my asset files:

```js
/*webpack.config.js*/
module.exports = {
  output: {
    assetModuleFilename: '[file]'
  },
};
```

However, this is not ideal as all files get overwritten by themselves.

Answer (score 3):

I found the following solution. In this example all files inside of the /asset folder are kept in place:

```js
/*webpack.config.js*/

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /^assets\/.*$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
        /* do not emit copies of files */
        generator: {
          emit: false
        }
      },
    ],
  },
  output: {
    /* use original file-path in generated output files */
    assetModuleFilename: '[file]'
  },
};
```

Unfortunately I found nothing about it in the official documentation, the answer is based on: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/pull/12871

For some reason this seems not to work with the `watch` option enabled
(tested with `webpack 5.44.0` and `webpack-cli 4.7.2`.)

Comment: This solution worked for me. I did not want the woff files to be bundled up but Webpack was creating the copies! By just adding the rules, I could stop Webpack from bundling the copies into my dist folder. Thank you!

Comment: This solution *almost* worked for me. Problem is, I use the @ character as a prefix in the css image paths. It's configured to resolve to wwwroot. The webpack build task needs to have it there, otherwise it can't resolve the image. However, the path that ends up in my outputted css files also contains 'wwwroot', and it shouldn't, because it's not part of the url.

Comment: I managed to craft a working solution by disabling all css image path url processing for the css-loader. I got it from https://stackoverflow.com/a/71429261/1018165.