# Webpack-5 - Webpack tries to resolve root-relative paths to images in scss (or css) and fails

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

## I'm getting this error after upgrading to Webpack-5:

`Error: Can't resolve '/path/to/image.jpg' in '/app/path/to/module/module'`

The issue is with images used for css backgrounds where the files aren't stored in the repository, and are not available at build-time. (Why it's this way is a story for another time.)

### The issue:

In my scss file:

```css
background-image: url(/path/to/image.jpg);
```

In Webpack-4, it was left as-is, and just worked.

Webpack-5 tries processing the image and fails with the error above.

### This didn't work:

Adding quotes to the path...

```css
background-image: url("/path/to/image.jpg");
```

I've tried Webpacks magic comments...

```css
/* webpackIgnore: true */
background-image: url(/path/to/image.jpg)
```

... but it didn't work (maybe they were getting stripped too early? - This seems to be the case as is evidenced by the dev build working in my [create-react-app example](https://github.com/dovidweisz/webpack-test))

[webpack.IgnorePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/ignore-plugin/)

I also tried some of the edge-case tips from [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/). But i think that comes in too late because Webpack already assumes that the file exists.

### This worked but...

What does work, is including the absolute path to the asset:

```css
background-image: url(https://www.example.com/path/to/image.jpg);
```

But that creates it's own set of problems.

### Update:

#### I reproduced the issue in [this repo](https://github.com/dovidweisz/webpack-test):

The Webpack magic comments work for the development build, but not for the production build.

```bash
~/webpack-test$ npm run build

> webpack-test@0.1.0 build
> node scripts/build.js

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/mypics/pom.jpg' in '/home/nodejs/webpack-test/src'
```

Comment: Are you able to provide your webpack config here or a link to it in a pastebin? That would probably help get this debugged

Comment: It's insanely complex, but want to reproduce it in an example project. Do you know of an example bootstrap project?

Comment: Maybe I'll just eject from create-react-app to get a boilerplate.

Comment: That would work!

Comment: @jaitaiwan I did it https://github.com/dovidweisz/webpack-test

Comment: Bravo! Well done

Comment: Filled a bug reporr too: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/15499

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that the css-loader has configuration options just for this under [`options.url`](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/#url)!

> Thank you [Alexander Akait](https://github.com/alexander-akait) from the Webpack team for answering my question [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/15499#issuecomment-1064323239).

It has the option to pass an object that contains a `filter()` predicate function that should determine whether a path should be processed:

```js
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        loader: "css-loader",
        options: {
          url: {
            filter: (url, _resourcePath) => {
              // Disable processing for root-relative urls under /images
              return !/^\/images\//.test(url)

              // This would disable processing for all root-relative urls:
              // return !/^\//.test(url);
            },
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Here is the commit I used to fix this issue in the repo mentioned in the question: https://github.com/dovidweisz/webpack-test/commit/a9e4cfc4ae0a5a8475ddd2cc114a8650846db421

You can also disable **ALL** url-handling by simply passing `false` to `options.url`:

```js
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        loader: "css-loader",
        options: {
          url: false,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: This fixed my problem right up. I added it to my .css and .scss rules. I get no more randomly named images in my dist folder, and the image paths are left untouched. They are absolute and remain so, in the output. This helps a lot, since I inline (= load into memory) them with Web Optimizer. This doesn't work with relative paths, since the path of the css changes when you inline it in a page on a different path as the source location of the inlined css. But since they stay absolute, now it does work. Tnx!